# Python subprocess call with %s and * inside adb shell

Tags: python, subprocess, adb, wildcard

I am learning python and i am loving it how it can help me automate some of my daily routines. I am using google for all my questions and till now I have been very successful. But this time i am really stuck and have already spent 2 days on this.

The below code does not work as there is %s and * in same line

```
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess as sp
regLists = ['1b7', '1b6', '209', '197']
valLists = ['23', '80', 'ab', '73']
for regs,vals in zip(regLists,valLists):
        sp.call('adb shell "echo %s %s > /d/asoc/*-snd-card*/*_code*/code_reg"'%(regs,vals), shell=True)
```

Error:

```
Error: /system/bin/sh: can't create /d/asoc/*-snd-card*/*_code*/code_reg: 
No such file or directory
```

- a) the path name is different for each device
- b) * is used to find the path name inside linux directory

Working Code is shown below as there is no * and the entire path is mentioned

```
sp.call('adb shell "echo %s %s > /d/asoc/xyz-snd-card-device45/ffde_code-fffb/code_reg"'%(regs,vals), shell=True)
```

Please can someone help how i can change the above code so that i can use above code...

Answer (score 0):

```
for regs,vals in zip(regLists,valLists):
    echo = "echo {} {} > /d/asoc/*-snd-card*/*_code*/code_reg".format(regs,vals)
    sp.check_call(["adb", "shell" , echo])
```

Comment: Sorry didnt work: print echo shows:
echo 1b7 23 > /d/asoc/*-snd-card*/*_code*/code_reg

Comment: Don't work is not a good explanation. What is the error you're having?

Comment: Sorry.. first time using Stack Overflow and Hit "enter" by mistake

ideal way echo should look like:
echo 1b7 23 > /d/asoc/xyz-snd-card-device45/ffde_code-fffb/code_reg

Comment: you use wildcards, so echo will redirect values to all files matching that primitive regex, one of them would be /d/asoc/xyz-snd-card-device45/ffde_code-fffb/code_reg i assume

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am very new to this and thus need sometime to understand what is check_call, and why it is not working.. please give me sometime.. thank you

Comment: So.. after much debugging.. seems like I need to get rid of the * in the echo string...
C:>adb shell "echo 197 80 > /d/asoc/*-snd-card*/*_code*/code_reg"
/system/bin/sh: can't create /d/asoc/*-snd-card*/*_code*/code_reg: No such file or directory

Comment: @tinySandy, your change makes the python code better but does not address the root cause of the error that Miraage is getting. his python code works just fine... that's his Android shell code which does not

Comment: because you failed to comprehend the problem before posting an "answer"?

Comment: if you failed to comprehend my answer doesn't mean that OP's code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the support.
I will certainly try the for and find option mentioned above to get more familiar with python programming. In the meantime, did more debugging on google and found another working solution as shown below.
By using the && operator, the code works as expected.

```
sp.call('adb shell "cd /d/asoc/*snd-card*/*_code* && echo %s %s > code_reg"'%(regs,vals), shell=True)
```

PS: I still need to check the difference between sp.call and sp.check_output

Comment: again. this code would also fail if your folder name pattern would expand to multiple entries.